# PHP on command line displays "Out of Memory", no file name, line number or memory value

Tags: php, centos, command-line-interface, memory-usage

I originally posted this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665189/php-on-command-line-displays-out-of-memory but was advised to post here instead.

This is not the normal fatal error when you run out of memory in a script, as it doesn't give a file name, a line number or the amount of memory used. It simply says "Out of memory" whenever I try to run php on the command line, either when you pass it a script or simply just run php by itself. Even trying to run a script that doesn't exist gives the same message.

In other words I get this:

```
dan@server [~]# php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php test.php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php doesntexist.php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php -v
Out of memory
```

However PHP through Apache works absolutely fine. It's just on the CLI that I get this error.

The machine in question is running CentOS release 5.7 (Final) which is 64 bit and PHP 5.3.10. It is a dedicated server.

I have tried running ulimit -a as dan as suggested and this is the output:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 200000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 200000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 37888
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 35
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

free -m on root gives this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3824       3714        110          0        142       2632
-/+ buffers/cache:        939       2885
Swap:         3490          0       3490
```

And the memory usage from top:

```
Mem:   3916648k total,  3797056k used,   119592k free,   145820k buffers
Swap:  3574452k total,      168k used,  3574284k free,  2686844k cached
```

**UPDATE:** Restarted the server yesterday and it worked for the rest of the afternoon. However, today it is doing the same thing.

Running "strace php test.php" (a file that exists), well it goes on for a while, but the last page or so in putty was this:

```
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=100030, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 100030, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2ad3ce0af000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23736, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2ad3ce0af000, 100030)          = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
futex(0x3d80e07b20, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x3d80e079a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x3d7fe94760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x3d7fe94c10, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/etc/krb5.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=608, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 4095) = 314
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/krb5.conf", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 4
read(4, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 4095) = 314
close(4)                                = 0
access("/etc/krb5.conf", W_OK)          = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=608, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ad3ce0af000
read(3, "[logging]\n default = FILE:/var/l"..., 4096) = 608
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x2ad3ce0af000, 4096)            = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0444, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
read(3, "\300\260\36co\363cI\t\355\324\3518gy\354\357\314Z:", 20) = 20
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x3d7f624640, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 4095) = 314
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/krb5.keytab", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 4095) = 314
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x3d8122d0c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/dev/urandom", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0444, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
brk(0x340b000)                          = 0x340b000
brk(0x342c000)                          = 0x340b000
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap(NULL, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap(NULL, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
write(2, "Out of memory\n", 14Out of memory
)         = 14
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

**EDIT:** Added outputs as requested by sonassi.

The entire log is available at http://www.2shared.com/file/05MVRFI6/dmp.html

Output from cat /proc/meminfo:

```
MemTotal:      3916648 kB
MemFree:        501180 kB
Buffers:        335276 kB
Cached:        2312536 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:        1312888 kB
Inactive:      1702096 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:      3916648 kB
LowFree:        501180 kB
SwapTotal:     3574452 kB
SwapFree:      3574292 kB
Dirty:             728 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:      367160 kB
Mapped:          33640 kB
Slab:           351564 kB
PageTables:      18588 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   5532776 kB
Committed_AS:  1188280 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    265828 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359471827 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

The output from cat /proc/meminfo after running php test.php is below. I have replaced the IP address of the server here as it is a public IP - xxx.xxx.xxx.11 is the main IP of the server and xxx.xxx.xxx.12 is the other IP.

```
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=3 ID=271 PROTO=UDP SPT=10170 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=89.39.188.210 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=47199 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2119 DPT=4899 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=89.39.188.210 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=47678 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2119 DPT=4899 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=89.39.188.210 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=48675 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2119 DPT=4899 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=198.60.169.59 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=16299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3185 DPT=5555 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=198.60.169.59 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.12 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=16300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3186 DPT=5555 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=198.60.169.59 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.12 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=17038 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3186 DPT=5555 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=198.60.169.59 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=17073 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3185 DPT=5555 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=188.254.224.225 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.12 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=39888 PROTO=TCP SPT=59828 DPT=5900 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=188.254.224.225 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=43041 PROTO=TCP SPT=59828 DPT=5900 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=269 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=269 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=2 ID=270 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=2 ID=270 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=3 ID=271 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=93.191.199.110 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=3 ID=271 PROTO=UDP SPT=10202 DPT=33437 LEN=12
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=65.111.170.208 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.11 LEN=444 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5105 DPT=5060 LEN=424
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=65.111.170.208 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.12 LEN=443 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5105 DPT=5060 LEN=423
TCP: Treason uncloaked! Peer 82.129.64.220:5306/59348 shrinks window 3410313698:3410313754. Repaired.
Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:23:ae:8f:59:78:30:37:a6:da:d2:e9:08:00 SRC=223.203.192.53 DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.12 LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=2742 PROTO=UDP SPT=0 DPT=0 LEN=44665
```

cat /etc/security/limits.conf shows that is all commented out as far as I can tell:

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - an user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

# End of file
```

And the output of cat /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

**EDIT:** Updated the ulimit above to run as dan, not root.

Comment: What does your /etc/php5/cli/php.ini look like?

Comment: Try running it through strace: `strace php`

Comment: What is the result of getenforce, this "Out of memory" could be a red herring and selinux is instead arresting the process due to a rule misconfiguration / bad lib being loaded by php.

Comment: Have posted the result of strace php test.php above.

Comment: To be honest, the first page of the strace might be helpful too (strace -o dmp.log php foo.php)

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit OS? Technically the Apache SAPI module and the CLI version of PHP are completely independent of eachother. So it's feasible for one to work and not the other.

Comment: I have uploaded it to http://www.2shared.com/file/05MVRFI6/dmp.html. The OS is 64 bit.

Comment: getenforce says "Disabled"

Comment: is only the "dan" user affected?  is php the only command that gives the OOM message?  Can you, for example, run a perl script?  Have you tried running 'ps' to see if your user has a bunch of running procs chewing up the allowed memory usage for dan?  what are the ulmits for the 'dan' user?

Comment: It never occurred to me to check to be honest - but looking now, dan is affected and so are some others (with the same problem), but others are not and work fine. root also works fine. I don't have any perl scripts, but perl - v works fine (on dan) and so does python.

Comment: Is this a VPS or dedicated machine? Can you provide the output from cat /proc/meminfo And after executing the PHP binary (and getting the associated "Out Of Memory" error), can you provide the output from dmesg | tail -n20 My knee-jerk response would have been ulimit, but the output above looks fairly un-restrictive. But could you provide the output of cat /etc/security/limits.conf And finally, the output of cat /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: @gnuffo1 You've provided a lot of helpful info, and I hate to request more, but can you provide `/proc/buddyinfo` when this issue is occuring?

Comment: Please run: `which php`, `rpm -qf $(which php)`, and `rpm -qf $(which php) --verify` .

Comment: The `meminfo`, `limits.conf`, `dmesg` and `sysctl.conf` all look normal (very standard in fact). So I would assume an issue with the PHP binary itself, or an extension (maybe compiled for a different version of PHP). Could you also provide a list of the PHP extensions you have installed (eg. APC/Eaccelerator/Xdebug etc.).

Answer (score 8):

***After re-reading your comments above*** and your original post - you ran `ulimit -a` as `root` - but you said that `root` is unaffected.

Your issue here **is** `ulimit`, but at a user level. Log in as your `dan` user and run `ulimit -a` and you will probably find your memory is limited.

Comment: I have updated the ulimit output above to run as dan.

Comment: @Gnuffo1 this appears to be the answer then. you have several settings limited to 200000 kb. If you adjust these settings higher you'll likely find it starts working.